# .NET: what's the downside of using shared dbContext per HTTP request (vs multiple dbContext, one for each Business Object)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

Say I have entities: **StudentDm** and **StaffDm**
And Business Objects that handles database queries: **StudentBo** and **StaffBo**

**Student** and **Staff** are 2 tables in the database that are completely unrelated.

I have been using the one DbContext per Business Object architecture, and Unit of Work to do Commit() using the shared DbContext per HttpRequest.

Here is the code for the base Business Object class **BaseBo**

```
public class BaseBo<T> where T : EntityBaseDm
{
    private CompassDbContext context;
    public DbSet<T> dbSet
    {
        get
        {
            CompassDbContext returnContext;
            if (HttpContext.Current.Items["UnitOfWorkContext"] != null)
            {
                returnContext = (CompassDbContext)HttpContext.Current.Items["UnitOfWorkContext"];
            }
            else // otherwise: we are not in unitOfWork
            {
                if (context == null) // if this Bo did not instantiated a context, instantiated it
                {
                    returnContext = context = new CompassDbContext();
                }
                else // otherwise get the already instantiated context
                {
                    returnContext = context;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the way I get the context from each Business Object is: I check if we are in UnitOfWork, if we are, get the shared context. Otherwise, instantiate a separate context for the Business Object.

I've been following this architecture since alot of books describe it as being the standard. Until today when I need to join two LINQ queries from **StudentDm** and **StaffDm**. And then it gives me error saying that since they are 2 different dbContext instantiated I cannot join them.

Then I changed my **BaseBo** so that all my Business Objects always share the same dbContext per HTTP request, regardless of if we are in Unit of Work or not.

Like this:

```
public DbSet<T> dbSet
    {
        get
        {
            CompassDbContext returnContext;

            if (HttpContext.Current.Items["CompassDbContext"] == null) // if this Bo did not instantiated a context, instantiated it
            {
                returnContext = context = new CompassDbContext();
                HttpContext.Current.Items["CompassDbContext"] = returnContext;
            }
            else // otherwise get the already instantiated context
            {
                returnContext = (CompassDbContext)HttpContext.Current.Items["CompassDbContext"];
            }

            return returnContext.Set<T>();
        }
```

I guess my question is: what's the downside of always using the same dbContext per HTTP request since a request is so short lived? Why is it okay for Unit of Work to share one single dbContext but not in general when you want to get data?

Comment: By using the first way, you can get out of the unit of work pattern - which is one of the advantage of EF. Where did you read it was a good practice ?

Comment: If you read [this](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/) all the way you'll be fully aware of the pitfalls of both approaches.